# C# - Manipulação de controles em evento disparados por um método multithread de outra classe

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Bom dia, pessoal.

Estou desenvolvendo uma biblioteca em C# usando o Visual Studio para autenticação/licenciamento de softwares. É algo simples. Consiste basicamente em um método que executa um loop contínuo verificando um arquivo xml contendo a data de vencimento da licença, a data da última atualização do arquivo e compara essas informações com a data e hora do pc.

Nesse método podem ser identificados três situações:

1. Licença autenticada
2. Licença vencida
3. Data/hora do pc retroagida

Cada situação dessas disparará um evento contendo essas informações de autenticação que deverá ser tratada dentro dos softwares que futuramente eu venha desenvolver, tal qual os eventos comuns de controles e outras bibliotecas do Windows. (No caso dessa minha biblioteca, é algo parecido com o controle timer, que dispara o evento tick a cada período de tempo)

Até aqui tudo funcionando bem. O problema ocorre quando eu vou usar essa biblioteca de autenticação em outro sistema pra exibir as informações de autenticação nos controles dos formulários para o usuário. Ocorre o erro: 'Operação entre threads inválida: controle acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.'

Encontrei alguns métodos que conseguem contornar esse erro, mas eles são implementados dentro dos programas e eu queria algo que pudesse ser encapsulado dentro dessa minha da biblioteca de autenticação.

Essa é a forma como os eventos são disparados:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(object sender, AuthenticationEventArgs e);
public event MyDelegate Authenticated;

public EsLicense(string FilePath, string Key)
{
    //Carregamento de outras propriedades
    
    this.t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OnAuthentication));
    
}

public void StartTimer(int interval)
{
    _interval = interval;
    _running = true;

    Load();

    if (!t.IsAlive)
    {
        Load();

        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }

}
    
protected virtual void OnAuthentication()
{
    while (_running)
    {

        // Cria um novo objeto do tipo AuthenticationEventArgs
        AuthenticationEventArgs e = new AuthenticationEventArgs();


        if (DateTime.Now <= this.LastUpdate) //Verifica o relógio
        {
            //EXECUTA QUANDO O RELÓGIO DO SISTEMA ESTIVER INCORRETO


            if (TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now)) //Verifica horário de verão
            {
                //Código para tratar erro quando o horário de verão acabar

                
            }

            // Verifica se existem métodos inscritos no eventos
            if (Authenticated != null)
            {

                // Define os argumentos do evento
                e.Status = AuthenticationStatus.SystemClockError;
                e.Remaining = this.Remaining;
                e.Exception = new Exception("O relógio do computador está desconfigurado. Configure a hora certa para poder continuar.");

                // Dispara o evento
                Authenticated.Invoke(this, e);
                //Authenticated(this, e);

            }

        }
        else
        {
            //EXECUTA ENQUANTO O RELÓGIO DO SISTEMA ESTIVER CORRETO


            this.Update(); //Atualiza o último acesso


            if (DateTime.Now < this.ExpirationDate) //Verifica a data de expiração da autenticação
            {
                //LICENÇA VÁLIDA

                //Define a quantidade de dias que faltam até o vencimento da licença
                this.Remaining = this.ExpirationDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

                // Verifica se existem métodos inscritos no eventos
                if (Authenticated != null)
                {

                    // Define os argumentos do evento
                    e.Status = AuthenticationStatus.Validated;
                    e.Remaining = this.Remaining;
                    e.Exception = null;

                    // Dispara o evento
                    Authenticated.Invoke(this, e);
                    //Authenticated(this, e);


                }

            }
            else
            {
                /*
                 * LICENÇA EXPIRADA
                 * 
                 */

                //Define a quantidade de dias que faltam até o vencimento da licença
                this.Remaining = new TimeSpan(0);

                // Verifica se existem métodos inscritos no eventos
                if (Authenticated != null)
                {

                    // Define os argumentos do evento
                    e.Status = AuthenticationStatus.Expired;
                    e.Remaining = new TimeSpan();
                    e.Exception = null;

                    // Dispara o evento
                    Authenticated.Invoke(this, e);
                    //Authenticated(this, e);

                }

            }

        }

        Thread.Sleep(_interval);
    }
}
```

Exemplo de método que tratará o evento:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Licença = new EsLicense(@"C:\licença.xml", key);
    Licença.Authenticated += new EsLicense.MyDelegate(Licença_Authenticated);
    Licença.StartTimer(1000);
}

private void Licença_Authenticated(object sender, AuthenticationEventArgs e)
{

    switch (e.Status)
    {
        case AuthenticationStatus.Validated:
            textBox1.Text = e.Remaining.ToString(); // Linha onde o erro é disparado
            break;

        case AuthenticationStatus.Expired:
            textBox1.Text = "Licença expirada"; 
            break;

        case AuthenticationStatus.SystemClockError:
            MessageBox.Show("Erro de autenticação.\n\nO relógio do computador foi desatualizado", "Autenticação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.Exit();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


}
```

Sou iniciante em C# e espero ter sido claro o suficiente.

Comment: você não precisa declarar um `event`e um `delegate`, em essência eles fazem basicamente a mesma coisa, tem diferenças técnicas, mas no seu exemplo basta um `event` para resolver o seu problema. Remova o `delegate` e faça invoke direto do `event`. Agora sobre a thread, explique melhor pq usa isso, é pq o programa pode monitorar multiplas aplicações, e cada uma executa numa thread?

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual, obrigado pelo comentário. Fiz o que você disse, removi o `delegate` e declarei o evento como `public event EventHandler<AuthenticationEventArgs> Authenticated`, mas o problema da thread continua. Eu preciso usar thread por causa do  `while` no método `OnAuthentication()`. Esse método atualiza e monitora o arquivo xml de autenticação a cada intervalo de tempo. Se eu não usar uma thread diferente a aplicação simplesmente trava. No exemplo acima eu coloquei a instancia da classe `EsLicense` no evento `click` do botão, mas na verdade será no evento `Load` do MainForm da aplicação

Comment: só o Timer não basta? ele por si só já é uma thread, se quer só que a cada X tempos ele olhe para o arquivo isso basta :)

Comment: Poderia sim, era dessa forma que eu usava essa biblioteca, mas gostaria de aprender mais sobre o funcionamento de eventos disparados por métodos multithreads de outras classes e a manipulação desses eventos usando os controles. Acho até que seria uma forma mais elegante de trabalhar sem usar componentes extras e encapsular o máximo de código possível pra reutilização.

Comment: nesse caso estude mais sobre o seu código, faça debugs.. vai perceber que seu código codigo criar uma thread e um timer, o que não faz sentido, apenas um dos dois resolveria isso, boa sorte

Comment: Justamente. Eu posso usar só timer, mas gostaria de usar só thread.